# I can't find the javaC.sublime-build

Tags: java, compilation, sublimetext2, libraries

I just started programming with SublimeText 2 and I was trying to add libraries so that my code would work.

But the problem is, everywhere I look on the internet, everyone says "Open the file **JavaC.sublime-build** and replace all the code in the file with the code below". The thing is, I'm unable to find it.

If I listen to what I read, it is supposed to be in "Java/jdkX.XX.XX/bin/" but I can't find it. Is it because I never managed to compile Java Code before ? Do I have to create it ? Or is it somewhere else ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Sublime 2, the file is easy to find. Open the **`Preferences`** menu in Sublime and select **`Browse Packages...`**. This will open the `Packages` folder in your operating system's file explorer. Browse down and open the `Java` folder, in which you will find `JavaC.sublime-build`. Open this file in Sublime using JSON syntax, and edit to your heart's content.

Comment: Yeah the problem was that in everything I read before, I couldn't think of looking at this very Java folder, I'd always go llok for the one in ProgramFiles. Proving I do not think well. (laughs) Thanks anyway.